# How to change color of the appending element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a "custom append" function that taking in two parameters and appending their's value in a one line. 
 I need to make the first parameter's value to append in a gray color but the second value have to stay as it is.
I tried to use a "css(property, name)" function but it didn't work.
Where is my fallacy and how to get a needed result?

```js
var showText = function(who, str) {
  if (str !== "") {
    var colorWho = who.name;
    colorWho.css("color", "gray");
    $("#storyBoard").append("<br>" + colorWho + ": " + str + "<br>");
    var element = document.getElementById("storyBoard");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
  }
};
```

Comment: appended element should be a `DOM` component like `div` or `span`. Ex. `<div style="color:gray">+ who.name+ </div>`

Comment: You have an odd mix of JS and jQuery going on here. Could you give a more complete example of both your HTML markup and how you actually call this method. It appears that `who` is an object that holds a `name` property at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pisha/wdmyrs3y/1/)

CSS

```
p > span {          /* If you're going to take this to a larger environment, you may want to use classes instead */
  color:gray;
}
```

JS

```
var showText = function(who, str) {
  if(str !== ""){
    var colorWho = who.name;
  $("#storyBoard").append("<p><span>"+colorWho + "</span>: " +str+ "<p>");
}

};

var obj = {
    name : "Preacher",
}

showText(obj, "Is an awesome comic book !");
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you require?

```
$("#storyBoard").append("<br><span style='color:gray;'>" + colorWho + "</span>: " + str + "<br>");
```